# How to retrieve a PHP value from DB and update on page with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a voting function which submits a user vote using AJAX and updates the DB without having to refresh the page. All good so far. But I also want to retrive the updated values from the DB and update this on the page.

I've nested a second AJAX request inside my first request. This second request calls on the file new_values.php which gets the latest values and puts them into an array and returns as JSON like below

```
     $new_vals = array(
        'new_total' => $new_total,
        'poll_option_1_val' => $poll_option_1_val,
        'poll_option_2_val' => $poll_option_2_val,
     );

    echo json_encode($new_vals);
```

Below is the Ajax request - the first request works just fine to update the DB but the inner AJAX request isn't working. In the below example I try to use alert to show new_total value but nothing happens

```
$(function () { // SUBMIT FORM WITH AJAX

    $('#poll-form').on('submit', function (e) { //on form submit

        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour

        if($("form")[0].checkValidity()) { // check if the form has been validated

        $.ajax({ // submit process

            type: 'post',
            url: 'vote-process.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {

                $('#vote_submitted').modal('show');
                $("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("textarea").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#vote_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#vote_button").text("Vote submitted");

                $.ajax({
                    url : 'new_values.php',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : data,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function (result) {

                      alert(result['new_total']);

                    },
                    error : function () {
                       alert("error");
                    }
                });
            },

            error: function() { 

                $('#error').modal('show');
            }     
        });
        return false;

      } else { // if the form is not valid

        console.log("invalid form");
      }
    });

});
```

This has been driving me crazy. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second Ajax data:data will give you this issue need to pass proper parameter

```
$.ajax({
         url : 'new_values.php',
         type : 'POST',
         data : {data_return:'yes'},
         dataType : 'json',
         success : function (result) {
            alert(result['new_total']);
         },
         error : function () {
            alert("error");
         }
    });
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. If you don't mind, could you please explain what {data_return:'yes'} is doing?

Comment: its parameter variable : you can pass anything in bracket like you want to perticulare record retrivew

Answer (score 0):

What is data in the second ajax request ?  data : data ? data is not defined so javascript maybe stop to execute entire code especially if use 'use strict'